# How do I change the look of the Menu Bar in Raspbian Jessie? Can I change UI transparency?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, raspbian-jessie

I want to change the way the interface looks and make things a bit easier on the eyes. The default look of the Raspbian OS is a little clunky for my taste and I was looking for something like the stuff I see in /r/unixporn.

Is Openbox a suitable Window Manager to affect these changes or do I need an alternative?